# Two identical hosts running identical service, but one fails to parse a WSDL

Tags: java, docker, soap, wsdl

We're in the following situation: We're provisioning new k8s clusters via automation, and building/deploying our microservices via automation as well. I've deployed several pre-prod clusters so far with no issue, but now we're into the integration testing environment and there is now a service container that is doing something *very* strange.

The container running on Host1 starts up as usual:

```
2020-12-10 00:46:39,717 INFO  [main] company.Api (Api.java:20) - Running against https://sandboxapi2.example.com/3.0/exampleApi.asmx with user company_example_api_user1
2020-12-10 00:46:39,864 DEBUG [main] resource.DefaultResourceManager (DefaultResourceManager.java:110) - resolving resource <org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl/bus> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
2020-12-10 00:46:39,865 DEBUG [main] resource.DefaultResourceManager (DefaultResourceManager.java:110) - resolving resource <null> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
2020-12-10 00:46:40,066 TRACE [main] helpers.DOMUtils (DOMUtils.java:83) - can't load class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl
2020-12-10 00:46:40,457 DEBUG [main] jaxws.ServiceImpl (ServiceImpl.java:430) - creating port for portName
2020-12-10 00:46:40,458 DEBUG [main] jaxws.ServiceImpl (ServiceImpl.java:431) - endpoint reference:
2020-12-10 00:46:40,458 DEBUG [main] jaxws.ServiceImpl (ServiceImpl.java:432) - endpoint interface:
2020-12-10 00:46:40,513 INFO  [main] factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean (ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:391) - Creating Service {http://api.example.com/}exampleApi from WSDL: jar:file:/lib/exampleclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/example.wsdl
...
```

But the container running on Host2 encounters fatal error when parsing the WSDL bundled into the container image:

```
2020-12-10 00:48:06,865 INFO  [main] company.Api (Api.java:20) - Running against https://sandboxapi2.example.com/3.0/exampleApi.asmx with user company_example_api_user1
2020-12-10 00:48:07,036 DEBUG [main] resource.DefaultResourceManager (DefaultResourceManager.java:110) - resolving resource <org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl/bus> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
2020-12-10 00:48:07,037 DEBUG [main] resource.DefaultResourceManager (DefaultResourceManager.java:110) - resolving resource <null> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
2020-12-10 00:48:07,231 TRACE [main] helpers.DOMUtils (DOMUtils.java:83) - can't load class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Both containers are deployed as pods in the same k8s deployment, just to different hosts in the cluster.

Things I've tried/verified:

- Images are uniquely tagged per-build, tags are never modified, and the container spec is using an appropriately specific tag, eg: `company/example:master.99-6920514A`, so we're definitely getting the same image on each host.
- No files or volumes are mounted to the container, all config is provided via environment vars.
- Re-provisioning the pods.
- Re-deploying all k8s resources associated with the service: deployment, configmaps, etc.
- Wiping the images from the machine and re-pulling.
- Shimming in the config and manually running the container.
- Validating the checksums of everything in the classpath match for containers launched on both hosts.
- Extracting the WSDL and verifying that there's no BOM or other data prefixed to the file.

  ```
  # jar xf /lib/exampleclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar example.wsdl
  # head -n 1 example.wsdl | hexdump -C
  00000000  3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65  72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31  |<?xml version="1|
  00000010  2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f  64 69 6e 67 3d 22 75 74  |.0" encoding="ut|
  00000020  66 2d 38 22 3f 3e 0d 0a                           |f-8"?>..|
  ```
- `xmmlint example.wsdl` raises no complaints.
- tcpdumping the container to verify that it's not making *any* network requests during startup.

We're all at the end of our ropes trying to figure out what is happening here. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this, or what we can check into further?

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.example.api.exampleApi.<init>(exampleApi.java:49)
    at com.company.Api.<init>(Api.java:27)
    at com.company.payout.Main.main(Main.java:43)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/s:schema[1]): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'file:/'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:830)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:320)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2352)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2338)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/; systemId: file:/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
    ... 17 more
```

### Edit: extra stuff tried

1. Stand up an additional node in the same zone, Host3

   - Service starts up just fine.
   - "Host2 must be haunted"
2. Remove Host2 from the k8s cluster, *delete*, and stand up a fresh one.

   - Service fails in the exact same way.
   - "Host2 must be *cursed*."

Again, this is the 3rd cluster. All of which are running ~30 other microservices without issue. All clusters are provisioned via Ansible and RKE, all services are deployed via Jenkins and Helm.

Comment: Different OS Versions ? Different Docker Versions ? Proxy,  Firewall networking on Host 2 ?

Comment: Both hosts were stood up simultaneously from the same playbook run. They have identical OS and Docker versions, and identical firewall config. They do reside in different subnets, but I've already checked the network from both which seems fine, as well as `tcpdump`ed the problematic host and found that it never actually makes _any_ requests while it's attempting to start up.